# Backbone Marionette: Rendering Collection in ItemView

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views

I was unable to find any posts relevant to this error. I am attempting to render a Backbone Collection in a Marionette ItemView.  The template is rendered, however, the data related to the collection is not rendered in the template. I am getting no errors or other indicators. For reasons I do not understand, using `setTimeout()` on `App.mainRegion.show(overView)`. However, I know that that is not an acceptable solution.  Could someone give me some insight on how to make an ItemView for a Collection properly render in this case? Here is my simplified code:

My Collection to be rendered:

```
About.Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: '/api/about',
    idAttribute: '_id',
});
```

Involved View definitions:

```
About.ListView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    tagName: 'ul',
    itemView: App.About.ListItemView,   
});

About.OverView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    tagName: 'div',
    className: 'inner',
    template: _.template('<h2>About Overview</h2><p><%= items %></p>'),
});
```

My relevant execution code:

```
var API = {
    getAbouts: function() {
        var abouts = new App.About.Collection();
        abouts.fetch();
    return abouts;
    },
    ...
}

var abouts = API.getAbouts();

var aboutsListView = new App.About.ListView({collection: abouts }),
aboutsOverView = new App.About.OverView({collection: abouts});

// Correctly renders collection data
App.listRegion.show(aboutsListView);

// Does not render collection data
App.mainRegion.show(aboutsOverView);

// unless
setTimeout(function() {App.mainRegion.show(aboutsOverView)}, 50);
```

For those who are interested, I am using an ItemView with the eventual intent to display aggregate data of `About.Collection`.  I will be happy to provide additional information, if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an issue with the asynchronous nature of the `fetch` call on your `collection`. The data for the `collection` has not returned when you show the two `views`. If you update the execution part of your code something like the following (untested), you should be on the right tracks:

```
var API = {
    getAbouts: function() {
        // Just return the new collection here
        return new App.About.Collection();
    },
    ...
}

// Fetch the collection here and show views on success
var abouts = API.getAbouts().fetch({
    success: function() {
        var aboutsListView = new App.About.ListView({collection: abouts }),
        aboutsOverView = new App.About.OverView({collection: abouts});

        // Should render collection data now
        App.listRegion.show(aboutsListView);

        // Should render collection data now
        App.mainRegion.show(aboutsOverView);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `abouts.fetch` call is asynchronous, and a significant amount of time elapses before the collection receives data from the server. This is the order in which things are happening:

- You call `getAbouts`, which itself calls `abouts.fetch` to make GET call to server for collection.
- The `listRegion.show` and `mainRegion.show` calls are made, rendering the 2 views **with the empty collection** (the collection hasn't received a response from the server yet).
- The GET call eventually returns, and the collection is populated with data.
- **Only the aboutsListView** re-renders to show the data (see below for the reason).

The reason that only the aboutsListView re-renders is that the Marionette CollectionView automatically listens for the collection's `reset` event, which is fired when the collection's contents are replaced.

You can fix this by simply adding an `initialize` function to your `OverView`, so that view also re-renders in response to the same event:

```
// add to About.OverView:

initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render);
}
```

That will take care of it.